# Problem with NDSolve with arguments(maybe?)

Tags: differential-equations

i have this scrit in mathematics 12 and it return this error: **"NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 3 in the first argument {(x^[Prime])[t]==x[t] (2-x[t]-2 y[t]),(y^[Prime])[t]==(2-2 x[t]-y[t]) y[t],3,3}."**

```
Clear [x, y, t]
f[x_, y_] := x *(2 - x - 2*y);
 g[x_, y_] := y*(2 - 2*x - y); 

Sol4 = NDSolve [{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], 
   x[0] = 3, y[0] = 3}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 7}];
```

Can you help mE?, what's wrong on my script?

Thansk a lot!

Comment: You need == while setting the initial conditions. You might find [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259) helpful too.

Comment: As Derke said, you needed `==` and not `=` (we all made such mistakes at some time). But I think It is better to write the odes, ics, each on its own line, then combine them.  This makes it easier to debug and see things. something like `ClearAll[x, y, t]
f[x_, y_, t_] := x[t]*(2 - x[t] - 2*y[t]);
g[x_, y_, t_] := y[t]*(2 - 2*x[t] - y[t]);
odes = {x'[t] == f[x, y, t], y'[t] == g[x, y, t]};
ic = {x[0] == 3, y[0] == 3};
sys = Flatten[{odes, ic}];
NDSolve[sys, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 7}]`

Comment: Hi Derek and Nasser, It's alive!! it's work!!!